# Laravel. Upload SQLite to server (MySQL)

Tags: mysql, database, laravel, sqlite

We decided to create project using Laravel, it's my first time using this framework.

Our hosting provides ability to upload files using FTP (no SSH access) and it supports MySQL (maybe it's not related, just mentioned, maybe we're using wrong hosting for Laravel project).

I followed some tutorials how to create SQLite database locally.

Is there any simple / standard way to migrate / upload my database to server (SQLite to MySQL)? Or it's bad practice at all?

Maybe I have to create MySQL database local too, instead of SQLite?

Could you share your experience and tell me what is the best practice managing database using Laravel framework?

Answer (score 0):

Seeing as you have no SSH access. I want to assume that you're using a shared hosting plan. If this is the case, the I suggest you export your local database using PHPmyadmin. After which you can upload it to your host. This is assuming your host has cpanel and phpmyadmin also.

If you would like to add a new migration later in production, just upload create a new migration locally and upload it to your server and call 
`\Illuminate\Support\Facades\Artisan::call('migrate');` anywhere in your code